# Can I change the Data Import Wizard Settings permanently?

Tags: lightning, data-import-wizard

When I select "Add new and update existing records," I'd like the defaults to always be "Match Contact by Email" and "Update existing Account information."  Can I make it save these settings, or do I have to select them every time?

Comment: Data Loader CLI ?

Comment: Not available to Essentials users. :( I have to use the Wizard.

Comment: Looks like Essential is pain. Sorry man .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Salesforce don't provide us the option to configure these setting permanently. We need to setup this every time we run the process.